# How to determine the midpoint of the parametric curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization, arc-length

Let us take the parametric curve r($t$) = [$\sqrt(t)$;$\exp(t)$], $t$ = [0,1]. Using this equation, I generate 1000 points (t = 0:1/999:1). Now my goal is to determine the midpoint of the curve (t=0.5) without using the equation of the parametric curve. To solve this problem, I estimated the geodesic distance from the starting point (t=0) to all points on the curve. The initial idea was to determine it by finding the point whose geodesic distance is half of the total length of the curve (t=0 to t=1). But the result is not satisfactory. Is there a way to determine the midpoint of the parametric curve by just using the dataset itself?

Comment: $t = 0.5$ does not necessarily imply that you are halfway the path

Comment: You are right that t=0.5 does not necessarily be the midpoint by length. But for me, selecting point with t=0.5 is more important than finding the point whose geodesic distance is half of the total length of the curve.

Comment: You cannot possibly do this. If you do not know the parametrization of the curve, you cannot know whether the particle moves with constant speed or whether it travels (almost, if you want) all the way to the other end during the first tenth of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-The curve $(\sqrt t,e^t);0\le t\le1$ and the "whole" curve $y=e^{x^2}$ are shown in the attached figure.

[image]

You can find directly the point for $t=0.5$ but for the midpoint of the curve you have to calculate $t_0$ such that  $$\int_0^{t_0}\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}dt=\int_{t_0}^1\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}dt$$

This $t_0$ gives you  the right point which almost surely will be distinct of $t=0.5$

Comment: My goal is to select the point among 1000 points whose t is close to 0.5. I am not allowed to use the equation of the curve. The prior knowledge is that we know the starting (t=0) and endpoint (t=1) of the curve and the path of the curve.

Comment: Okey. Good luck in your purpose. And welcome to MSE.

Comment: @BikramKoirala: what do you mean by "we know the path of the curve" ? I suspect that this is false.

Comment: It means that we can reach the final point (t=1) from the starting point (t=0) by connecting neighbor points.

Answer (score 0):

Your curve is monotonic in $x$ (also in $y$). Hence sort the points on $x$ (if necessary), and take the $500^{th}$.

---

**Disclaimer**: this assumes that your $1000$ points are sampled regularly, using the specified $t$ parameterization, and that the monotonicity condition holds.

Comment: I liked your suggestion, but this will not solve the problem when the dataset is sampled non-uniformly.

Comment: @BikramKoirala: read my disclaimer. And also ponder other comments that tell you that what you try to achieve is **impossible**.